# Perl script invoking ssh2 command fail to get output back in windows task scheduler

Tags: windows, perl, task, scheduler

I can run the Perl script from command line without any issue, but when I try to automate this task by using Windows Task Manager (64bit Windows 2008 Server), the output from SSH/SSH2 cannot be written to the outfile. It is a perl script, and it does something like this:

```
my $DB_FILE1=$PATH . "\\FSBusinessUtil_" . $hostfqdn . $DATE;
open( OUTFILE,  ">$DB_FILE1" )      or die "Could not open data file ";
print OUTFILE "FilesystemInfo\n";   

my $output1=`$SSH_PATH\\ssh $user\@$hostname NAS_DB=/nas /nas/bin/./nas_fs -list`;

if($? != $RC_OK){
    open( OUT1FILE, ">$PATH\\errFSBusinessUtil_$hostfqdn$DATE");
    print OUT1FILE localtime(time) . " Remote ssh failed to create $DB_FILE1. Error: $output1\n"; 
    close OUT1FILE;
}
else {
    $output1=~ s/%%%/\n/g;
    print OUTFILE $output1;
}  
close OUTFILE;
```

The Perl script itself got invoked by the Windows Task Scheduler, but in the output file, all I saw is the "FilesystemInfo" line the script prints out before invoking the ssh command. Besides that, the command did fail, because I saw the error file generated. But still, $output1 is empty so nothing but "Remote ssh failed to create... Error:".

Comment: I'd start debugging it by printing out the full ssh command before running it to see if its all correct.  I'd also suspect that the Task Manager may not have access to the same ssh keys or ssh agent as you do.  As a side note, look into using [lexical filehandles](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and you won't have the sort of conflicts you had to work around.  Very confusing names.

Comment: Just a note: forward slashes can be used in all path names in Windows, and this is considered a better practice because it reduces character escaping confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problems usually arise because the environments used when you run the program manually and when it is run from the scheduler are different. `ssh` is specially sensible to that as it stores user and host keys in files in the user folder.

The first thing you should try is to run ssh from your script in debugging mode:

```
ssh -vvv ...
```

Another possibility is to use [Net::SSH2](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aSSH2) that does not use any information from the environment and so, is not affected by that kind of problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comments. I did try "ssh -vvv", but I did not get any output in the $output1. And I tried to do the "Perl script_name > an_output_file approach, and it did not work. The task is ran as the same user. We tried to run as "SYSTEM", and we did see the problem you mentioned about the user and host key. I guess the question here is how to get the stderr output returned from the command in the backtick somewhere we can see. Thanks!

Comment: @Libby Shen: use something like `ssh -vvv ... 2>c:\\stderr.out`

Comment: Mystry solved! In the windows task scheduler, the "Run with highest privileges" was checked and that interfered with the SSH. Once that is unchecked, the Perl script was executed smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues while running SCP and SSH inside a scheduled VBscript.  Checking off "Run with highest privileges" did the trick.